Segmentation fault (core dumped) if I install any Python library or run a Python program
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
VERSION_CODENAME=noble
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=noble
LOGO=ubuntu-logo

RAM status:
$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62Gi       2.3Gi        58Gi       112Mi       2.6Gi        60Gi
Swap:           79Gi          0B        79Gi


Available disk space:
$ df -h     # for disk space
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              6.3G  2.8M  6.3G   1% /run
efivarfs                           192K  155K   33K  83% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  826G   78G  707G  10% /
tmpfs                               32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M   12K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p2                     2.0G  216M  1.6G  12% /boot
tmpfs                               32G     0   32G   0% /run/qemu
/dev/nvme0n1p1                     1.1G  6.2M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1                          9.1T  370G  8.3T   5% /home
tmpfs                              6.3G  104K  6.3G   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs                              6.3G   88K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000

Everything is fine, but I always get this error if I install any Python library or run a large program for data handling, etc. Then the program  crashes and shows this error.

Can you give a specific library that causes this crash?  Please add that to your question.
